# Scroll to the bottom of the page, reload it then repeat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have checked all the possible questions that could be related to this but I cant seem to find anything that suits my case, either the answers were not good or incomplete.

In my case I have a `html` page with some `php`, displaying competition results. As the competition is live the page with results should scroll to the bottom of the page and then the page should refresh (so the possible new scores come in) and then repeat again and again. What would be the best solution for my problem?

The page size/length would increase as more data will come in the tables which are on results page.

Image: [image: Site preview]

**EDIT**:

This code now scrolls to the bottom of the page and then jump back to top and repeat and its exactly what I want, but I would like a page to `refresh` every time I hit the bottom and `after this` go to the top.

```
$(function() {


  var pageScan = {
      speed : 10000,
      loop  : true,
      delayRestart : 1000, 
      start : function(){
          pageHeight = $('body').height() - window.innerHeight;
          pageScan.proc(pageHeight);
      },
      proc  : function(to){
          $("body").animate(
              {scrollTop: to}, 
               pageScan.speed,
               "linear",
               function(){
                  if (pageScan.loop) {
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                          pageScan.start();
                      }, pageScan.delayRestart);
                  }
          });
      }
  };

  pageScan.start();

  });
```

Comment: It's 2016 now use AJAX.. angular etc.

Comment: So lets say you have a page of height 900px height, you want to scroll to the bottom, and now reload the page and the height of the page increases, lets say to 1300px now you want to continue scrolling from 900 to 1300 or start from top ie 0- 1300 ??

Comment: I want to scroll from the top to the botom again.@Reddy

Comment: `location.reload();`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afm5471r/3/), have a look at the console to see that the page reloads before jumping to the top.

Comment: Figured out a similar solution but yours looks much better. @WcPc

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747119/4173280) answer. This trick might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some JavaScript to your page:

```
<script>
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
setTimeout(function (){location.reload()},5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
// Test data, ignore
for(i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    $('#results').append('<p>Test Result No.' + i + '</p>');
}

// Check every second (for example) if there is new data
// In this example there is always data
window.setInterval(function(){
  update_results();
}, 1000);

// Check for new results
function update_results() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // Test data, ignore
    data: {
      html: 'new result'
    },
    // your ajax.php file
    url: '/echo/html/',
    success: function(data) {
      // Append new results to $('#results');
      // You might want to give back an array and loop through it with $.each(data, function() {});
      // you might also want to check for "false" if there are no new results
      $('#results').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');

      // Scroll to bottom smoothly
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
    }
  });
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbcyvj82/)

In your ajax.php-File you can echo the new scores:

```
echo json_encode($scores);
```

Given that $scores is an array of your scores which you probably have from your database.

Comment: I don't want to update results this way I just wanna refresh the page when i hit the bottom. @WcPc